# I need help about arrays

Tags: c

Program Explain:

1/2/3

2 3 5

2 9 4

2 5 7

if i write 1in up it give me 2+9+7

if i write 2in up it give me 5+9+2

if i write 3in up it give me (2+9+7)-(5+9+2)

(BUT IT GIVES WARING:

*** stack smashing detected ***: unknown terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

)

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main()
    {
        int whatUDo;
        int square[2][2];
        int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0;
        int threeTime = 3;
        scanf("%d", &whatUDo);

        while (counter1 < 3)
        {
            scanf("%d", &square[0][counter1]);
            counter1++;
        }
        while (counter2 < 3)
        {
            scanf("%d", &square[1][counter2]);
            counter2++;
        }
        while (counter3 < 3)
        {
            scanf("%d", &square[2][counter3]);
            counter3++;
        }
        int first = square[0][0] + square[1][1] + square[2][2];
        int second = square[0][2] + square[1][1] + square[2][0];
        int third = first - second;

        if (whatUDo == 1)
        {
            printf("%d", first);
        }
        else if (whatUDo == 2)
        {
            printf("%d", second);
        }
        else if (whatUDo == 3)
        {
            printf("%d", third);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: After `int square[2][2];` you have an object capable of accessing 4 elements, namely `square[0][0]`, `square[0][1]`, `square[1][0]`, and `square[1][1]`. Attempt to access `square[2][0]` (or `square[0][2]` or `square[2][2]` ...) is a **BIG NO-NO**

Comment: when you declare a variable of type array, the numbers you put in the brackets is size, in mean you have 2 rows and 2 columns which their indexes start from zero, then it will be just 0 and 1. you have to increase size of your matrix to 3, like int square[3][3]

Comment: @pmg It started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

The size of your array is wrong.

---

For the code you have provided, you have to declare your array as

```c
int square[3][3];
```

Because the boundaries you are handling are from 0..2 and 0..2, respectively. The number you specify when declaring the array is the size, not the maximum index allowed.

In other way, if you declare:

```c
int myarray[5];
```

The items of your array are accessed from 0 to 4, and your array has a capacity of 5 items accessed by the indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.